# How to watch anime in India legally?

Tags: crunchyroll, india

I'm wondering how I can watch anime in India legally when we don't have any channel right now **AND** Crunchyroll doesn't release anime for India.

Comment: Are VPNs legal in India? This is called [geo-blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-blocking) and you can use a VPN to get around it. India may have laws around this, and I know none of India's laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muse Asia is now streaming anime for free via YouTube in Asia
And There are about 120 shows offered on Crunchyroll in India with 160 on Netflix and about 30 through Amazon Prime. but crunchy roll is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Unless the streaming company actually releases for your region, there is no **legal** way to consume that media.

Comment: This is wrong. As one country has said this is legal - "[The Copyright Act does not make it illegal to use a VPN to access overseas content. While content providers often have in place international commercial arrangements to protect copyright in different countries or regions, which can result in ‘geoblocking’, circumventing this is not illegal under the Copyright Act.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150415235330/https://www.malcolmturnbull.com.au/policy-faqs/online-copyright-infringement-faqs#VPN)"

Comment: @Peilonrayz:  It seems that you're referencing an Australian FAQ.  To be blunt, the *ideal* approach  to consume media online is to just go straight to the online streaming site.  There's a specific reason that geoblocks exist at all, and circumventing may not be illegal in one country, but may be illegal in another.  We are ***not*** here to determine what jurisdictions are OK to use a VPN with and which ones aren't, so I would much rather err on the side of caution and explicitly state, if it isn't permitted by the main streaming service without workarounds, it's probably not legal.

Comment: If you [edit] your answer so that it's inline with what your comment says then I'd remove the downvote. However currently you've just said something that is false.

Comment: @Peilonrayz:  It's not *false*.  The nature and relationship of VPNs and streaming sites [is ***complicated***](https://www.vpn.com/streaming/streaming-services-and-vpns/).  There is a fundamental difference between being *able* to leverage a VPN to consume media, and being *permitted* to use a VPN to consume media.  I refuse to give jurisdiction-sensitive advie, and since I'm definitely not in India, the more appropriate answer is that it's just not allowed so long as a geoblock exists.  It would suck to go buy a VPN to later get denied access because that site decided to block your VPN.

Comment: I believe you are more than capable to change your answer from absolutes.